# PL/SQL developer with oracle 32-bit/64-bit client

Tags: plsqldeveloper, oracleclient

I have Oracle 64-bit client installed to run with my weblogic application. I learnt that pl-sql developer doesn't work with oracle 64-bit client so now i have both 32-bit and 64-bit clients installed on my machine and my ORACLE_HOME variable points to 64-bit client.

I am not able to start pl/sql developer even i specify the 32-bit client in Tools->Preferences of pl-sql developer version 8.0.4.

I changed my oracle client to 32-bit client then i was able to start pl-sql developer but my application doesn't work.

Is there a way i can run PL/SQL developer whilst pointing ORACLE_HOME to 64-bit oracle client. I am not sure specifying the ORACLE_HOME explicitly in Tools->Preferences of pl sql developer (for user/default as well as system preferences) has any effect as it picks the oracle home from the environment variable i believe.

Thanks,
Adithya.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You'll need to install the two clients into separate Oracle Home locations, for example I've gone for `C:\OracleHome` and `C:\OracleHome32`

Then set up an Environment Variable, called TNS_ADMIN with the folder that contains your default TNSnames.ora file as the value (for me it is `C:\OracleHome\network\admin`)

Keep your preferences in PL/SQL Developer, and make sure you also specify the OCI library (mine is `C:\OracleHome32\oci.dll`)

Finally, using regedit.exe, add a second key under ORACLE (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE`). I've called mine KEY_OraClient11g_home1 and KEY_OraClient11g_home2. Create the same 4 strings in the second key, with the appropriate changes to the data (e.g. ORACLE_HOME should have `C:\OracleHome32` as it's data field in my example)

Restarting all applications should now let you use PL/SQL Developer seamlessly, whilst also defaulting to the 64-bit Oracle home for your weblogic application.

Answer (score 11):

To fix this, download the 32-bit version of **Oracle Instant Client**, extract it to a directory such as `C:\instantclient`.

Next, configure PL/SQL Developer to use this version by clicking on *Tools -> Preferences*. Under *Connection -> Oracle Home*, point to the location where you had extracted Instant Client (`C:\instantclient`), and under *Connection -> OCI library*, point to the oci.dll file in the same directory (`C:\instantclient\oci.dll`).

Restart PL/SQL Developer and you should be able to connect.

Answer (score 2):

This is an updated answer specifically for the Oracle 19 instant client and PLSQL Developer 13, which is 64 bit.

To make PL/SQL Dev work with the client, I went to :
 Configure -> Preferences -> Oracle\connection -> set oracle home to the new home dir, in my case, c:\oracle\product\19.x.

Do the same for the OCI : C:\oracle\product\19.x\instantclient_19_6\oci.dll

If you're migrating from an order version, you probably have built up a list of databases in your tns_names.ora. That will have to be moved over to the new client directory tree.

Manually make a subdir network\admin under the 19.x root. Once restarted, the Database list under 'Define Connection' had my list.

Answer (score 0):

Quick post: I was trying to connect to a 64-bit Oracle database using PL/SQL Developer. Despite ORACLE_HOME being set the right values and oci.dll available, PL/SQL Developer could not connect to the database.

Further probing indicated that the Oracle installation was a 64-bit one, and PL/SQL Developer is incapable of loading 64-bit version of oci.dll file. To fix this, download the 32-bit version of Oracle Instant Client, extract it to a directory such as \instant_client.

Next, configure PL/SQL Developer to use this version by clicking on Tool menus -> Preferences. Under Oracle Home, point to the location where you had extracted Instant client (\instant_client, in this case)  and under location of OCI Library, point to the oci.dll file present in location where you had extracted Instant client ( \instant_client\oci.dll). Restart PL/SQL Developer and you should be able to connect now.

open given link to download oci.dll file
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html

---